# Can I use these PHP functions together?

Tags: php

Can I use these PHP functions below:

```
$user = mysql_escape_string($user);
$user = filter_var($user, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user = stripslashes($user);
$user = trim($user);
```

together like this:

```
$user = mysql_escape_string(stripslashes(trim(filter_var($user, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))));
```

sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Sure you *can* use them together. Whether it makes sense is the real question. What's the goal? Also note that the first code snippet is not in the same order as the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var_filter validate or sanitize your var according to a list of predefined filters: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL.

trim and stripslashes are old school way to sanitize your vars

mysql_escape_string sanitize your querys for mysql, therefore this function are deprecated, you must use mysql_real_escape_string, the syntax is identical.

var_filter are most elegant and have many options from trim and stripslashes

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Answer (score 3):

I think the most sensible function order in your case would be:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(filter_var(stripslashes($user), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
```

Few notes:

- use mysql_**real_**escape_string, not the old variant
- use stripslashes() first, but more optimally: get rid of magic_quotes in the php configuration, or undo the quoting centrally  http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php#91585
- FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING does not add a whole lot of security (it's just strip_tags)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in terms of PHP's capabilities, but **please for the love of god no** for the sanity of anyone who needs to read code that after you; or you, who will be reading that code in six months time and wanting to hurt yourself really bad.

Also, it should be (functions called last should be placed outermost, according to your example -- not any form of sanity so **revise your code and don't do this -- this is purely educational!**):

```
$user = trim(stripslashes(filter_var(mysql_escape_string($user), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
```

In terms of practicality, `mysql_real_escape_string($user)` should be all you need to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Of course, filtervar-stripslash-trimming an SQL escaped string is about the worst thing you can do. :o)

Comment: thanks! could you enlighten me on which order i should do so and what to leave out and possibly anything i should add to the string?

Comment: @mcbeav That depends on what you *need to do.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however your example is in wrong order - be aware. And it not easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand mysql_escape_string() is all you need to prevent SQL injection.  If not, please leave a comment so I may be enlightened :)

Comment: Only if you're actually using MySQL, though. Other databases have different syntactical foibles which msyql_real_escape_string() wouldn't cover.